# Finding sum involving nth root of unity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am unable to prove that :

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} e^{(k^2-l^2)\frac{2\pi i}{n}} =n $$

I will be giving a talk on proof of quadratic reciprocity through linear algebra tomorrow.  Please, need urgent help.

Note: $n$ is an odd number, $n>1$.

"The proof involves purely linear algebra, firstly finding the trace and determinant of the matrix

$$A=(\zeta^{(i-1)(j-1)})$$  $$1\leq i,j \leq n $$ (n odd) and using it to deduce the law.

The above sum is precisely the square of the absolute value of trace of A."

Comment: I will be giving a talk on proof of quadratic reciprocity through linear algebra tomorrow. That's why.

Comment: I need a proof without using Gauss sum.

Comment: @metamorphy Note that $n$ is just odd -- not necessarily prime.

Comment: Would you please edit the question? (With just a few words on how did you use it in the proof. It would bring some interest and give a reason to the community to reopen it. In its current state, the question is going to be simply deleted. Not a big pity, but...)

Comment: Well that is a fine suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$; then $\zeta^m$ is well-defined for $m\in[n]:=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, $\zeta^m$ depends only on $m\bmod n$). So the given sum can be written as $\sum_{k,l\in[n]}\zeta^{k^2-l^2}$. As $n$ is odd, the map $(k,l)\mapsto(k+l,k-l)$ is a *bijection* from $[n]\times[n]$ onto itself (the inverse map is given by $(u,v)\mapsto\big((u+v)/2,(u-v)/2\big)$, well-defined as $2$ has an inverse modulo $n$). Hence $$\sum_{k,l\in[n]}\zeta^{k^2-l^2}=\sum_{k,l\in[n]}\zeta^{(k+l)(k-l)}=\sum_{u,v\in[n]}\zeta^{uv}=n$$ since $\sum\limits_{v\in[n]}\zeta^{uv}=0$ when $u\neq 0$.

Comment: Elegant answer. Thanks a lot.